# Как правильно указать обобщённый тип Т?

Tags: c#, generics

Не могу понять из-за чего появляется ошибка Требуется тип, подскажите как правильно привести к обобщению, чтобы можно было использовать `T.CompareTo(T)`.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Test
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    
        }
      }
    
      public class Check<T> : where T : IComparable<T>
      {
        //internal bool Min(T value,T min)
        //  => value >= min ? true : false;
      }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `: where T :` -> `where T :`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!